# ERC721 as DAO voting

Tags: nft, erc-721, dao, voting

I'm attempting to create ERC-721 with Dao voting power. Firstly, I want to make an ERC721 nft of different types like hero nft, legend nft, rare nft, uncommon nft, and common nft. Is it possible to make this into a single collection?If that's the case, I'd like to give them different voting powers, such as a hero NFT holder having 250 votes, a legend NFT holder having 150 votes, a rare NFT holder having 25 votes, and so on for the other two.
Could you please let me know if this is possible or if you have any suggestions?
or share any article.

Comment: I think you should use ERC-1155.